# Window 200x200 with circle 200x200 doesn't fit

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do something very simple. I'm trying to create a window that has a circle in it that fits perfectly. I made the window 200x200 and the circle 200x200 and it looks like this[image]

This is the code I made:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class HalloForm : Form
{
    public HalloForm()
    {
        this.Text = "Hallo";
        this.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        this.Paint += this.tekenScherm;
        this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
    }

    void tekenScherm(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {

        tekenSmiley(pea, 0, 0, 200);
        /*pea.Graphics.DrawString("Hallo!"
                               , new Font("Tahoma", 30)
                               , Brushes.Blue
                               , 10, 10
                               );*/

        //pea.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, )

        //pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(new Point(x + 40, y + 40), new Size(50, 50)));
        //pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(new Point(x + 110, y + 40), new Size(50, 50)));
        //pea.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, new Point[] { new Point(x + 85, x + 120), new Point(x + 115, y + 120), new Point(x + 100, x + 90) });
    }

    private void tekenSmiley(PaintEventArgs pea, int x, int y, int grootte)
    {
        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(grootte, grootte)));
    }
}

class HalloWin3
{
    static void Main()
    {
        HalloForm scherm;
        scherm = new HalloForm();
        Application.Run(scherm);
    }
}
```

I tried different auto scale modes and none of them changed anything. Can you help me find out why the circle doesn't fit in the window. I understand that maybe it wouldn't fit vertically because the top bar might be included in the height, but then it should still fit horizontally.

Comment: You are using Windows10, it uses transparent borders.  They are still there (hover the mouse near them), just hard to see.   You need to set the ClientSize property to get the guarantee that it is going to fit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that works indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned, the `Size` of the form includes borders, title bars etc. So, try to set the `ClientSize` which defines the client area of the form:

```
this.ClientSize = new Size(200, 200);
```